# Select only integers from a column of mixed data types in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` as shown below. The column `col2` has null values, blank values, integers and even float values. I want to derive a new dataframe `new_df` from `df` where the column `col2` has only integer values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
col2 = ["25.45", "", "200", np.nan, "N/A", "null", "35", "5,300"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": col1, "col2": col2})
```

This is how `df` looks:

```
  col1   col2
0    a  25.45
1    b       
2    c    200
3    d    NaN
4    e    N/A
5    f   null
6    g     35
7    h  5,300
```

Below is my desired output for `new_df` where the column `col2` values are only integers:

```
  col1   col2  
2    c    200
6    g     35
```

I have tried using pd.to_numeric() and even isdigit() functions but they are expecting a series as input. Is there an easy way to get the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `str.isdigit`

Filter out digits and select by boolean indexing:

```
df2 = df[df.col2.astype(str).str.isdigit()]    
print(df2)
  col1 col2
2    c  200
6    g   35
```

P.S., to convert "col2" to integer, use

```
df2['col2'] = df2['col2'].astype(int)
```

---

#### `str.contains`

You could also use `str.contains`, albeit slower, since it uses regex.

```
df[df.col2.astype(str).str.contains(r'^\d+$')]

  col1 col2
2    c  200
6    g   35
```

---

#### `pd.to_numeric`

A third solution is somewhat hacky, but uses `pd.to_numeric`. We need one pre-replace step to filter out floats.

```
v = df.col2.astype(str).str.replace('.', '|', regex=False)
df[pd.to_numeric(v, errors='coerce').notna()]

  col1 col2
2    c  200
6    g   35
```

Comment: Thank for for the quick response. I tried the `str.isdigit` method from your solutions and it worked perfectly as required. I also had tried the same method previously. But the only difference was that I did this - ~new_df = df[df['col2'].isdigit()]~. I was getting an error message ~AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isdigit'`. Your solution was exactly what was required.

Comment: @Code_Sipra It needs to be `df['col2'].str.isdigit()` (see the `.str` accessor bit there)

Comment: Just curious to know why we should be adding an extra `.str` when we have already converted the column to a string using `astype(str)`. That is what I had missed and I am sure many novices like me may attempt to do the same thing I tried to do.

Comment: @Code_Sipra Check this section of the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html), it should make things clear.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the same question but with slightly different data; imagine that we have the same dataframe, but now with a third column that has a column with strings, integers and floats (including np.nan).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
col2 = ["25.45", "", "200", np.nan, "N/A", "null", "35", "5,300"]
col3 = [25.45, "", 200, np.nan, "N/A", "null", 35, "5,300"] # new column with mixed types

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": col1, "col2": col2, "col3": col3})
```

```
print(df)


    col1    col2    col3
0   a       25.45   25.45
1   b       
2   c       200     200
3   d       NaN     NaN
4   e       N/A     N/A
5   f       null    null
6   g       35      35
7   h       5,300   5,300
```

To select just integers:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.col3.apply(lambda x : isinstance(x, int))]
print(df2)

    col1    col2    col3
2   c       200     200
6   g       35      35
```

And just floats:

```
df3 = df.loc[df.col3.apply(lambda x : isinstance(x, float))]
print(df3)


    col1    col2    col3
0   a       25.45   25.45
3   d       NaN     NaN
```

(note that np.nan is a float)